# How to only display 'Edit' link on certain rows on apex interactive grid in apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive report apex5.0 which contains several fields. Would like to disable 'edit' option link where Request_type is null. Link is to be enabled only where Request_type is null. Disable the edit link and show the value of request type.

What are the different options to do this kind of functionality in apex5.0, enable & disable "EDIT" based on certain criteria?

Answer (score 1):

The most secure method is to conditionally generate the link using apex_util.prepare_url and apex_page.get_url within your SQL, instead of the declarative link.

You need to set Escape Special Characters to No for this column.

Comment: its not related to what i asked :-(

Comment: It's not? See slide 58 for example of this, which looks exactly as you described http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/12/a-dozen-things-to-do-with-oracle-apex.html

Answer (score 0):

If your link is rendered as a column in your interactive report, you can put a Condition on it based on a PL/SQL Expression, e.g.

```
:REQUEST is null
```